# How to display array where one param is key in html

Tags: html, angular, typescript

```
{
    "Id": "12345",
    "length": [
        {
            "review": {
                "1": {
                    "request": [
                        {
                            "days": "20"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
console.log(data.length[0].review[1].request[0].days) // returns "20"
```

In my typescript i am able to print the days as 20 perfectly. I am trying to the same in html so I have a for loop for my length like

```
<div *ngFor=" let item of length; index as I" >
<span *ngFor=" let a of item.review[1].request >
{{a.days}}
</span>
</div>
```

but `review[1]` is not working in html. its working in typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed in your html code's 1st ngFor loop, the `let item of length` is not defined properly. Instead it should be the some val.length. Like below:

```
x = {
    "Id": "12345",
    "length": [
      {
        "review": {
          "1": {
            "request": [
              {
                "days": "20"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }


<div *ngFor=" let item of x.length; index as I">
  <span *ngFor=" let a of item.review[1].request" > {{a.days}}</span>
</div>
```

This should solve the issue.. Please verify..

Comment: if  i am providing review.one its working fine..but review[1] is not working in html

Comment: I made a stackblitz with the data provided and it seems to be working fine. Please verify..  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxnm5s?file=src/app/app.component.html